# How to set function parameter in update statement with value from each row?

Tags: kdb

I have a table and a function:

```
table:([] id:til 5; name:("one";"two";"three";"four";"five"))
fu:{[x] x,"_",x}
```

And I want to apply the function in an update statement on each row and set the result into a new column 'xyz'. How can I do that? 
This here does not work, as it seems to evaluate the argument as a list:

```
xyz:update x:fu[name] from table
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the each-both operator to ensure the function runs on each row separately:

```
q)update xyz:fu'[name] from table
id xyz
----------------
0  "one_one"
1  "two_two"
2  "three_three"
3  "four_four"
4  "five_five"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use each-both: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both

```
q)update xyz:fu'[name]from table
id name
----------------
0  "one_one"
1  "two_two"
2  "three_three"
3  "four_four"
4  "five_five"
```